# Creating an entity from an api call and a schema map

Tags: oop, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I am deciding how I should create an entity which I pull from a 3rd party api. The concept of my entity requires two API calls, one of which pulls the unique data about the entity, and the other which gives me a full schema of all possible data that could belong to an entity.

I've already written a repository for the entity, but where does the schema map fit in the domain layer if I'm only going to grab it once?
How should the entity hold this schema data?
I'm not familar with the mapper pattern, but does that seem like this is the right use case for it?

Comment: If I understood your question right then you want a Object which holds data and as well as metadata?

Comment: Yeah, that actually sounds like what I want

Comment: Verify if third party API provides any metadata for the object it returns. Just create a Map<String, Class> model where you map the model information to the class name. You don't need to represent metadata in your domain model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have schema data and then data then you're dealing with an entity with dynamic properties, akin to a dictionary or hashtable, but with validation.

You could treat the schema data as an entity of its own, that provides the *knowledge level* to instantiate and validate entities, which lie on the *operational level*.

Take a look [here (pdf)](http://martinfowler.com/apsupp/properties.pdf) for many related patterns.